# Accessing my outlook inbox via php code

Tags: php, email, outlook, imap

How i can access my outlook account through my php code? I need to get the subject, from address and attachment. And then i need to mark the accessed as read on outlook. 
I have already accessed gmail account using IMAP but now i want to access outlook account.

Is it possible?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: "Outlook" as in "outlook.com account"?

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko, yes....any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ALERT DEPRECATED code: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/clients-and-mobile-in-exchange-online/deprecation-of-basic-authentication-exchange-online

==================

Finally i got a solution, i can access the outlook account using IMAP in PHP.

```
$hostname = '{outlook.office365.com:993/imap/ssl/novalidate-cert}INBOX';
    $username = 'username';
    $password = 'password'; 

/* try to connect */
$inbox = imap_open($hostname,$username,$password) or die('Cannot connect to '.$hostname.': ' . imap_last_error());
```